# Get differences between MyDoxyFile and the default Doxyfile

Tags: doxygen

How can I get the differences between my Doxyfile and the default one?.
I have been looking for this question in internet but did not found anything. And it seems there is no information on this in the man or info for doxygen.

Answer (score 1):

### Doxygen version 1.8.15 and above

Run `doxygen -x <your_doxyfile>` and it will list the differences.
Sample Output:

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.15
PROJECT_NAME           = MyProject
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = doc/
```

### Previous Versions

- create a new Doxyfile: `doxygen -g new_doxyfile`
- in case your Doxyfile is from the same version of doxygen as the above mentioned file:

  - *nux: `diff new_doxyfile <your_doxyfile>`
  - Windows: `fc new_doxyfile <your_doxyfile>`
- in case your Doxyfile is from a previous version

  - update the Doxyfile
    `doxygen -u <your_doxyfile>`
  - compare the files (see above)
- in both cases post **ONLY** the parts related to `<your_doxyfile>`

Comment: This works, but I think there is a typo: to create the  new_doxyfile, the parameter should be -g, not -u, I think.

Comment: In the upcoming version (1.8.15) and now in the github master version an option has been build in (`-x`) to show these differences.

Comment: https://meldmerge.org/ is also nice for viewing differences

Comment: @ferdymercury meldmerge (and other diff tools) can do a good you finding differences between 2 files, though `doxygen -x` has (in my opinion) the advantage that it parses the configuration file and sees what the differences are compared to the default doxygen settings (even when they are far apart in the used configuration file.

Comment: Agreed. I really like the -x option.

On an unrelated note, a more 'programatic' way of dealing with Doxyfile maintenance in big CMake projects could be to use doxygen_add_docs https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html
Here, one only specifies the non-default arguments, thus it is clear from the beginning what is being set. The advantage of this approach is that one does not need to 'update' the Doxyfile for deprecated tags as often, as it is generated on the fly with the current doxygen version.